# Get delivery status after sending sms via gsm modem using AT commands

Tags: php, gsm, at-command

My php file has the following code:

```
$serial->deviceOpen();

$serial->sendMessage('AT+CMGF=1'); 
$serial->sendMessage(chr(13));
$serial->sendMessage('AT+CMGS="+3XXXXX"');
$serial->sendMessage(chr(13));
$serial->sendMessage("THIS IS  TEST");
$serial->sendMessage(chr(26));

sleep(6);

$read=$serial->readPort();
```

My code includes AT commands and it can now send sms to any number via gsm modem. Now I want to obtain the delivery status. I have used the AT commands for delivery status in putty software and got correct results. I want to see the report by my php code. How can this be done?

Comment: on every send write data on text file.. using fopen and fwrite

Comment: sorry I didn't understand.Could you please provide me a helpful link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check delivery status by new incoming sms that will inform about success. It should not be hard to access it via this AT cmds:

```
AT+CNMI New SMS message indication
AT+ CMGL List SMS messages from preferred storage
AT+CMGR Read SMS message
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable the delivery status report by CNMI command, then enable the request for delivery report by CSMP command.

```
AT+CNMI=2,1,0,1,0
AT+CSMP=49,167,0,0
```

The first argument in CSMP command, 49, indicates the request for delivery report to the GSM network. If delivery report is not required, simply use 17 instead of 49.
Then send your SMS using CMGS command.
The delivery report would be reported to the host from the modem by +CDS URC code.